# How to get random objects from list of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

```
let data = {
  "physics": {
    "adsd12354asd": {
      "question": "This is the question physics 1",
      "options": ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
      "correctOption": "Option 2"
    },
    "4589asdasdasd": {
      "question": "This is the question physics 2",
      "options": ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
      "correctOption": "Option 2"
    },
    "asdasds435679d": {
      "question": "This is the question physics 3",
      "options": ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
      "correctOption": "Option 2"
    },
    "aasdfgsdasds435679d": {
      "question": "This is the question physics 4",
      "options": ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
      "correctOption": "Option 2"
    },
    "asdasds4356adiut9d": {
      "question": "This is the question physics 5",
      "options": ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"],
      "correctOption": "Option 2"
    }
  }}
```

Choose 3 random object from 'physics'.

I used this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data.physics);
var randomKey = keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length)];
var value = data.physics[randomKey]; 
console.log(value)
```

but it only returns one object,
if I use it in the loop then if I have thousands of data it may be challenging to perform a loop.